# Typo in `dplyr::percent_rank`?

Tags: r, dplyr

In trying to understand what 'percent_rank' does, 
I took a peek at the code and found the expression `length(!is.na(x))`.  I can't think of any situation in which `length(x) != length(!x)` 
so I'm wondering if this is a typo (perhaps it should be `sum(!is.na(x))`?) or if here really is such a situation??

Comment: I would agree with you. Claims to scale to the range of 0,1, and `dplyr::percent_rank(1:10)` would return 1 but `dplyr::percent_rank(c(1:10, NA))` would not.

Comment: Nice catch.  The same issue is present in `cume_dist()` too.  I submitted a pull request based on this post: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/pull/1133

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug.  This code was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/f5e2752ab7570475d6d2df864946ad3e4223661c), which is a stated response to [issue 774](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/774).  Hadley writes in issue #774:

> Oh oops, I'd say that's a bug in my R implementation. **The denominator
> should be the number of non-NAs, not the length.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> We don't need options to control behave, just ensure that NAs in input
> are NA in output

But as you note, it should have been `sum(!is.na(x))` not `length` to implement the intended fix.

Answer (score 1):

From `?is.na` I see two possibilities:

1. The first is that if the default method of `is.na()` is used, then it is documented to return "a logical vector of the same length as its argument `x`, containing `TRUE` for those elements marked `NA` or, for numeric or complex vectors, `NaN`, and `FALSE` otherwise." (from `?is.na`, Value section).

   Hence you are correct in surmising that there isn't a case where `length(is.na(x)) != length(!is.na(x))`.
2. If a non-default method were applied, the author of that method could return an object that is incompatible with the documentation of the generic (and default method). In that case, all bets are off.

   I find this option to be a bit of a stretch, but it is possible if perverse.

I suggest you report the Issue on Hadley's github repo.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a matter of preference. Even the help says:

> x a vector of values to rank. Missing values are left as is. 
>   If you want to treat them as the smallest or largest values,
>   replace with Inf or -Inf before ranking.

If you decompose `percent_rank` to individual elements and apply to a sample vector you get:

```
> x <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, NA)
> left  <- rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") - 1
> right <- length(!is.na(x)) - 1
> out   <- left/right
> out
[1] 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.75   NA
> x[is.na(x)] <- Inf
> left  <- rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") - 1
> right <- length(!is.na(x)) - 1
> out   <- left/right
> out
[1] 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.75 1.00
```

I am fine with how the function works right now. You just need to make sure that `NA` is changed to `Inf/-Inf` if you would like to get always 0-1 range. What I am not sure about, if this matches SQL2003 standard.

Comment: I'd argue that in your first example, the `NA` values are being treated inconsistently: as the largest values, as they depress the other outputted values - yet they are also left "as is" in that they return NA.  Regardless, if it were intended to function like this, having the current denominator code call `!is.na` for no reason would be an odd way to implement.  See the link in my answer to the relevant GitHub issue for some discussion of the intended functionality.